# Creating a VIEW to get a connection count

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a table below which stores Connections between 2 person

```
TABLE (CONNECTION)

ID | REQUEST_PERSON | REQUESTEE_PERSON
```

I would like to build a VIEW  which gets the REQUEST_PERSON, REQUESTEE_PERSON and MUTUAL_CONNECTION_COUNT(other common connections count between them). Any help is appreciated

For Example if we have a table data as below

```
ID | REQUEST_PERSON | REQUESTEE_PERSON
1    A                B
2    A                C
3    B                C
4    D                B
5    D                A
6    A                E
7    B                E
8    A                F
9    C                G
```

I need a VIEW display below

```
ID | REQUEST_PERSON | REQUESTEE_PERSON  | MUTUAL_CONNECTION_COUNT
1    A                B                   3
2    A                C                   1
3    B                C                   1
4    D                B                   1
5    D                A                   1
6    A                E                   1
7    B                E                   1
8    A                F                   0
9    C                G                   0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain Why this is the correct output.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added a row C, G on the table now to give more combinations

Comment: Why doesn't the output have a row for `C, D`?  Which ***appears*** to have a mutual connection count of 2 *(`DA -> AC` and `DB -> BC`)*.  This is why it's important you read the link I gave you, and actually explain WHY the output is what you desire *(what **exact** logic is being implemented)*.

Comment: I want to have the same number of records in the VIEW as in the TABLE with just an additional column in the VIEW which is mutual connection count

Comment: That explains the rows, you still have not explained how the values in `MUTUAL_CONNECTION_COUNT` is derived.  *(Did you actually read the link I supplied you on this question and your previous, now deleted, question?)*

Comment: Yes. I did. I think MUTUAL_CONNECTION_COUNT was explained where the table stores connection between 2 person and for each connection. we want to get the count of other common/mutual connections between them. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather tricky.  Here is code that does what you want:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*)
        from (select v.person2
              from connections c2 cross apply
                   (values (c2.REQUESTEE_PERSON, c2.REQUEST_PERSON), (c2.REQUEST_PERSON, c2.REQUESTEE_PERSON)
                   ) v(person1, person2)
              where v.person1 IN (c.Request_Person, c.Requestee_Person) 
              group by v.person2
              having count(*) = 2
             ) v
       ) in_common    
from connections c
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f42fb22e2a3e13c9f75a7e628dc6ee3) is a SQL Fiddle.

The essence of the problem is finding people who are connected to both people in each row.  Your connections are unidirectional, which makes the logic hard to express -- C could be either the first or second person in either connection.

Arrgh!

So, the innermost subquery adds reverse links to the graph.  Then, it can focus on filtering by the first person -- who has to match the persons in the outer query.  The second person is the one that might be in common.

The inner aggregation is just summarizing by the second person.  It filters using `having count(*) = 2` to indicate that both people in the outer query need to be connected to the second person in the inner query.  The `count(*)` assumes that you have no duplicates.

Then, these are counted, which is the value you want.